# How to migrate Hibernate from MySQL to SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I need to migrate my JPA/Hibernate (5.1) Java EE application from MySQL to SQL Server (2012). Since the abstraction provided by JPA, my humble thought was about this being simple and straightforward.

I started loading the SQL Server JDBC 4.2 drivers on Wildfly 10, downloaded from Microsoft website, and defining the new datasource resulting in a successful connection test.

Then, I republished my application letting Hibernate reconstruct the database tables, but I'm stuck on this:

```
13:27:29,268 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) SQL Error: 1038, SQLState: S0004
13:27:29,268 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
13:27:29,270 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."best.war#best": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."best.war#best": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: best] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: best] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing table metadata
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.locateTableInNamespace(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTable(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.getTableInformation(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:251)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:36)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1834)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1793)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1839)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setCatalog(SQLServerConnection.java:2190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.switchCatalogs(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:331)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetFromStoredProc(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:282)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetWithProvidedColumnNames(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getTables(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.locateTableInNamespace(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:339)
    ... 19 more

13:27:29,278 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "best.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"best.war#best\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"best.war#best\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: best] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: best] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing table metadata
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as \"\" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name."}}
13:27:29,300 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "best.war" (runtime-name : "best.war")
13:27:29,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."best.war#best": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."best.war#best": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: best] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

What's happening? This is my `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="best" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasource/mssql/best</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
  </persistence-units>
</persistence>
```

I tried also adding this, since I'm on SQL Server 2012, but nothing changed:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
```

Any idea or suggestion?

**Update**

Issue seems to happen only with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update`, since with `create` it works. But I really need `update` to work like it did with MySQL, since I'm on heavy development and my schema changes frequently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server requires explicit **catalog** and **schema** settings.

additional description in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
<property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="[database name]" />
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dbo" />
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
```

---

refs:

- [java - Problem using Hibernate and SQL Server 2008 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3159852/4506703)
- [java - JPA GenerationType.AUTO not considering column with auto increment - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047226/)

Comment: hibernate.default_catalog=[database name] fixed it, thanks!!

Comment: This is a bug in my pov. It worked in 4.3 very well. Now Hibernate does not issue the correct query to SQL Server if in @Table only schema is specified and no catalog! I raised a bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10978

Comment: Thanks! For those struggling to set up a Quarkus application talking to mssql:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-catalog=DBNAME
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema=SCHEMANAME
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem rises when you use @Table with a schema value but no catalog value and no hibernate.default_catalog is specified in persistence.xml.

This is a bug in my pov. It worked in 4.3 very well. Now Hibernate does not issue the correct query to SQL Server if in @Table only schema is specified and no catalog! I raised a bug here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10978

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and SQL Server both have some specific keywords or reserved names.

Check that your entities don't use any as table name or column name.

Comment: They don't, it's all JPA defaults. I have no `@Table`s nor `@Column`s, but I've found that the issue is only with `update` DDL, with `create` works.

Comment: Did you try switching to update again? You write above, that you set the dialect only after problems appeared, maybe there was some kind of unrecoverable schema mismatch introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using hibernate **5.1.0.Final** with SQL Server 2012. I downgraded to hibernate **4.3.11.Final** and solved the problem.

Hibernate EntityManager 5.1.0.Final

```
INFO  Version:37 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
INFO  Environment:213 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO  Environment:317 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
INFO  Dialect:156 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
INFO  Version:30 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 1038, SQLState: S0004
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - Falta o está vacío un nombre de objeto o columna. Compruebe si todas las columnas de las instrucciones SELECT INTO tienen un nombre. Para otras instrucciones, busque si hay nombres de alias vacíos. No se permiten los alias definidos como "" o []. Cambie el alias por un nombre válido.
```

Hibernate EntityManager 4.3.11.Final

```
Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Version:30 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
SchemaValidator:157 - HHH000229: Running schema validator
SchemaValidator:165 - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
TableMetadata:65 - HHH000261: Table found: rino.rino.tipo_ticket
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this thread here but landed here when I could not get Spring Boot JPA working with MS SQL Server the way it worked with MySQL and Postgres.

This thread has been very helpful with Spring Boot **1.5.9.RELEASE** which uses Hibernate **5.0.12.Final**.

Also note that many tutorials show the Spring Boot application.propeties file with entries for the database and hibernate which have now been superseded with newer properties by Spring Boot.

So if you are using Spring Boot with Microsoft SQL Server, use the following style of properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;jdbc.databaseName=mydb
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=aadmin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.database=sql-server
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

And in your entities you need to provide the following schema information:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(schema="dbo", name="MyUser",catalog="mydatabase")
public class MyUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public MyUser() {
    }

    public MyUser(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", Age=" + age + '}';
    }
}
```

Note: The `catalog` attribue of the `@Table` annotation should be your database name. It is required for connecting and accessing Microsoft SQL Server when using the combination of Spring Boot and Hibernate as mentioned above.