# Query to create a new table to a specific database in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 3 databases `sytemdatabases`,`smoketest` and `learnqueries` .

Every time i write and execute create table query `(create table tablename (colname datatype(size)))`, a new table is created in the `systemdatabases`.

I need it to be created to smoketest database.
I tried on this query `(create table  smoketest.newtablename(number int,name varchar(50));`

```
It is showing an error (Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

The specified schema name "smoketest" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.) when i executed it.

It says 2 chances

1. Database does not exist - but the database exists
2. Does not have permission - what does it mean -how to set permission to create a
   new table to a specific database

Pls help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [4 part 'dot' notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419127/sql-dot-notation) in Sql Server for tables is

```
Server.Database.Schema.Object
```

So you would need to create the table with at least 3 parts if `smoketest` is not the current database on your connection, e.g. if you are on `master`, and assuming you want the new table in schema `dbo`:

```
create table smoketest.dbo.Tablename(ID INT)
```

Alternatively, switch to the `smoketest` database and create the table with 1 or 2 part naming:

```
use smoketest
GO
create table dbo.Tablename(ID INT)
GO
```

Answer (score 10):

```
USE smoketest
GO

create table newtablename(number int,name varchar(50));
```

If you have a permission issue, check out this [SQL Server 2008: how do I grant privileges to a username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username)

Hope this helps.