# Multiple 2 different colums from 2 different databases

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am producing this

```
Inpatient Days NICU rate    
1              900.00
```

These two columns are listed on different databases on different servers
so database a has `inpatient days` and database b has `nicu rate`.
How do I multiply `Inpatient days * Nicu rate` and get a new column called total allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144070/2560997

Basically just do the next:

```
select *
from LocalTable, [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[dbo].[OtherTable]
```

Answer (score 0):

If both db in the same server, then the syntax is

```
select 
    a.quotename[Inpatient Days], b.quotename[NICU rate]    
from 
    databasename.a ,databasename.b
--where condition if there, other wise cartesian product result comes
```

If both db in different database , then as above suggest use link server syntax.

you can replace this heirarchy by DOT(.)

[SQL dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419127/sql-dot-notation)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/is-it-okay-to-put-dots-in-sql-server-database-names