# it does not exist or you do not have permissions when executing SQL IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, asp.net-core

I want to turn on IDENTITY_INSERT before inserting data into the database. But when I run my code it throws an error

> "Cannot find the object "UniversityDB.StudentRegistrationModels"
> because it does not exist or you do not have permissions"

**My control code is:**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StudentId,CourseId,IsPaymentComplete")] StudentRegistrationModels studentRegistration)
{
    using (var db = new UniversityDBContext())
    {
        db.StudentRegistration.Add(studentRegistration);
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT UniversityDB.StudentRegistrationModels ON;");
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT UniversityDB.StudentRegistrationModels OFF");
    }
}
```

**and database model is:**

```
public class StudentRegistrationModels
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student"), Required]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Course"), Required]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaymentComplete { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentModel Student { get; set; }
    public virtual CourseModels Course { get; set; }
    
}
```

Please help me to  fix it

Comment: `StudentId` shouldn't be an identity column anyway since it's also a foreign key. But the exception tells that the database isn't even found (i.e. not accessible).

Comment: You don't specify a schema so if this is SQL Server for instance it would default to "dbo". Try `SET IDENTITY_INSERT UniversityDB.dbo.StudentRegistrationModels ON` assuming your database name is UniversityDB.

Comment: isnt the default schema dbo? hence it should be `dbo.StudentRegistrationModels`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419127/sql-dot-notation)

Answer (score 0):

If something wrong in turn on/off IDENTITY_INSERT, The error message will be: `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'xxxxxxx' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

But your error message is not that. So I presume that `UniversityDB.StudentRegistrationModels` doesn't map correctly to a table in your database.

You can try to modify your code in the following format:

> **SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ [ database_name . ] schema_name . ] table_name { ON | OFF }**
>
> database_name Is the name of the database in which the specified table
> resides.
>
> schema_name Is the name of the schema to which the table belongs.
>
> table_name Is the name of a table with an identity column.