# SQL Server 2008 R2 how to change dbo.tablename to Domain\UserName.T_TableName

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Question: when I create a table (`T_TableName`) using SQL Server Management-Studio, it always creates the table as

```
dbo.T_TableName
```

instead of

```
Domain\UserName.T_TableName
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: There's **nothing wrong** - that's the way SQL Server works. Each database has a **default schema** which typically is `dbo` - if you don't specify anything else, all new database objects will be created **in the default schema**

Answer (score 0):

It is also known as `Database Owner`.
Database Owner is the default schema in SQL Server.
Database Owner offers simplified  ways to group objects.

`dbo` is a special schema - it is is present in every database and, typically, it is the default schema for users. It stands for "database owner". If you do not explicitly specify a schema when you refer to an object,

SQL Server will go to the default schema. This is perhaps why you sometimes see this schema and sometimes not. NOTE that it is typically considered bad practice not to explicitly state the schema when referring to an object, so whereas you are keen to not qualify all objects with the schema name, if I got hold of your code I would add the schema name in.

Answer is Reffered From one of my Favourite author :
[See](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1659139-dbo-table-prefix)

These are some link Please refer this also.
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062075/why-do-table-names-in-sql-server-start-with-dbo)