# What is MC in a table or store procedure SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my database there are a table that is declared like MC something like this

```
CREATE TABLE [MC].[tb_products]()
```

What is it for? Or what is?

Comment: It is a schema. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062075/why-do-table-names-in-sql-server-start-with-dbo

Comment: Is the `SCHEMA` where your table is going to be created.   Like a subfolder inside your db

Comment: ok just is the schema name

Answer (score 2):

`[MC]` is a database schema. Advantages to using it are logical grouping and being able to control permissions.

See: [What is purpose of database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674222/what-is-purpose-of-database-schema)