# What does 'dbo' stands for in MongoDB - Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

Here is the code example:

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(require("./routes/record"));
// get driver connection
const dbo = require("./db/conn");
 
app.listen(port, () => {
  // perform a database connection when server starts
  dbo.connectToServer(function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
 
  });
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

db/conn.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const Db = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(Db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
 
var _db;
 
module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function (callback) {
    client.connect(function (err, db) {
      // Verify we got a good "db" object
      if (db)
      {
        _db = db.db("employees");
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB."); 
      }
      return callback(err);
         });
  },
 
  getDb: function () {
    return _db;
  },
};
```

I've done some research and it stands for 'Database Owner' in SQL Server but it doesn't make sense here.

These code examples are from [MongoDB official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial) and why do they assign connection instance as dbo if it really stands for Database Owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation provides no explanation for the choice of variable name, we can only guess. My best guess is that dbo stands for database object, considering the type of the export.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is idiosyncratic usage mimicked from the SQL world where `dbo` is [the default schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062075/why-do-table-names-in-sql-server-start-with-dbo) and abbreviates ***d**ata**b**ase **o**wner*.

Typically, and in the [MongoClient documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#open), I see just `db = require("./db/conn");`  But it appears here that the author's fingers are just used to automatically typing an `o` after typing `db`.

Humans are habitual imitators. I wouldn't think too much of it.  It's just a variable name.

Comment: lol, and i always thought it's database object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction and built-in parameters name in `nodejs`.

You can use that according to your preference

Comment: What "parameters" name?

Comment: like you select dbo as parameter name ..
we can consider that as database-object