# What are schemas in PrestoDb?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I am reading this post that explains concepts in presto.

I am really confused by the definition of Schemas. The post says

> Schema is what you use to organize your tables.

This is confusing to me because I have always thought of schema's as a way to describe the shape of a table. Ie the columns present and the types of the columns.

So this line is telling me Schema is a way to organize my tables? What does that even mean?

I am familiar with databases like MySQL, and I have mostly interacted with databases, and the tables contained within those databases

Presto seems to be introducing another concept of Schemas? And I find this confusing how it fits into the big picture.

So please what exactly are schemas in prestoDB?

Answer (score 0):

> Presto seems to be introducing another concept of Schemas?

No, it does not.

Have not worked with MySQL but other databases like SQL Server ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-schema?view=sql-server-ver16), [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062109/2501279)) and Postgres ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html)) has the same concept of schemas (just schemas, not table schemas) too - they are used to organize tables in the database. From the PostgreSQL docs:

> There are several reasons why one might want to use schemas:

> - To allow many users to use one database without interfering with each other.
> - To organize database objects into logical groups to make them more manageable.
> - Third-party applications can be put into separate schemas so they do not collide with the names of other objects.