# Renaming multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I have a database `abc`. In this database I have hundreds of tables. Each of these tables is called `xyz.table`

I want to change all the tables to be called `abc.table`.

Do we have a way by which I can change all the names from `xyz.table` to `abc.table` in database `abc`?

I am able to manually change the name by changing the schema for each table to abc

Comment: Hi. What version of SQL-server do you use? Am I right that you want to change schema of all tables in a database?

Comment: Thanks @Igor for looking into. I am using sql server 2008. You are right i want to change schema of all the tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Alter Schema with an undocumented Stored Procedure exec sp_MSforeachtable which basically iterates through all the tables .

```
  exec sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER SCHEMA new_schema TRANSFER ? PRINT '? modified' "
```

change the new_schema keyword with your new Schema .

For details please go through the link

[sp_MSforeachtable](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)

[Alter Schema for all the tables](http://xman892.blogspot.in/2007/02/sql-server-2005-change-schema-for-all.html)

As others have pointed out that the SP is deprecated so  There is another way to do this by getting the names of the table from sys.tables

```
Declare @value int
Set @value=1
declare @sql varchar(max), @table varchar(50), @old varchar(50), @new varchar(50)

set @old = 'dbo'
set @new = 'abc'

while exists(select * from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = @old)

begin
;With CTE as
 (
  Select *,row_number() over(order by object_id) rowNumber from sys.tables 
  where schema_name(schema_id) = @old
 )
 select @table= name from CTE where @value=rowNumber
 Set @value=@value+1

 set @sql = 'alter schema ' + @new + ' transfer ' + @old + '.' + @table

 exec(@sql)
 end
```

Comment: What if the database has tables in the `xyz` schema, but *also* in a `def` schema, and the OP wants to move only those tables from the `xyz` to `abc` ?

Comment: marc_s : I have updated my reply .Without using cursor we can change the schema .

Comment: That might work, too - in my testing, however, it ended up in an endless loop for the last table..... also: being really nitpicky: the input to your `exec()` function should be of type `nvarchar(...)` (but that's really really nitpicky, agreed!)

Comment: Thanks Marc_s .Agreed i should be changing it to nvarchar

Answer (score 8):

You could have a cursor run over all your tables in the `xyz` schema and move all of those into the `abc` schema:

```
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
FOR
    -- get the table names for all tables in the 'xyz' schema
    SELECT t.Name
    FROM sys.tables t 
    WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('xyz')

DECLARE @TableName sysname

OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName

-- iterate over all tables found    
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(999)

    -- construct T-SQL statement to move table to 'abc' schema
    SET @Stmt = 'ALTER SCHEMA abc TRANSFER xyz.' + @TableName
    EXEC (@Stmt)

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Comment: why do we need a cursor? this can be done using a single-line `T-SQL` statement using inbuilt stored procedure.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: yes - with an **undocumented** procedure that is not guaranteed to be there in the next release of SQL Server. Cursors will still be there - for sure. Also: this approach can move those tables from the `xyz` and leave anything else alone (as requested) - can you "one line of T-SQL" do the same?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer, Here  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/] Aaron Bertrant reported about breaks of sp_MSforeachtable.  `Sadly, I have discovered instances where, under heavy load and/or with a large number of databases, the procedure can actually skip multiple catalogs with no error or warning message.`

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer Sorry, the right link is http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2201

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer - That procedure uses a cursor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming You've already created the schema `abc` in the database.

If not you can refer here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DDgv8uek6M

http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2008/tutorial/sql_server_database_schemas.cfm

To change the schema of all the tables in database you can use following system created [msforeachtable](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm) stored procedure to rename schema of each table with [alter schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx).

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER SCHEMA abc TRANSFER ? PRINT '? modified' "
```

Comment: What if the database has tables in the `xyz` schema, but *also* in a `def` schema, and the OP wants to move only those tables from the `xyz` to `abc` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without using the undocumented/unsupported `sp_MSforeachtable` procedure, here's a somewhat concise way to select and/or run all of the necessary ALTER statements for every table on the given schema:

```
declare @oldSchema nvarchar(50) = 'abc'  -- usually 'dbo'
declare @newSchema nvarchar(50) = 'xyz'  -- use your new schema name

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
(select
  (select N'alter schema [' + @newSchema + '] transfer [' + @oldSchema + '].[' + name + ']
' as 'data()'
   from sys.tables
   where schema_name(schema_id) = @oldSchema for xml path(''), type)
 .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'))

-- You can select out the results for scrutiny
select @sql

-- Or you can execute the results directly
exec (@sql)
```

This avoids using a cursor, and uses brackets to escape table names that may conflict with SQL keywords.