# Change Schema Name Of Table In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, schema

I want to change schema name of table `Employees` in Database. In the current table `Employees` database schema name is `dbo` I want to change it to `exe`. How can I do it ?

Example:

FROM

```
dbo.Employees
```

TO

```
exe.Employees
```

I tried with this query:

```
ALTER SCHEMA exe TRANSFER dbo.Employees
```

But this gives me an error:

> Cannot alter the schema 'exe', because it does not exist or you do not
>   have permission.

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you [created the exe schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx)?

Comment: Does the schema exe exist?

Comment: No I didn't create. What should I do to create it ?

Comment: run `create schema`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189462%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: I saw this article but it is little confusing. Can you show me how to create the schema in my situation ?

Answer (score 381, accepted):

**Create Schema :**

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'exe')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [exe] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END
```

**ALTER Schema :**

```
ALTER SCHEMA exe 
    TRANSFER dbo.Employees
```

Comment: Can you explain what is sys.scemas and EXEC(...) function ?

Comment: `sys.schemas` is a table that contains all the schemas for the database. The Exec('...') just runs a dynamic SQL call, in this case it is needed because a CREATE SCHEMA command must be the first statement in a query batch and executing as dynamic SQL gets you this.

Comment: For **all  Tables** , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1149168/2218697) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10943302/2218697) to do it in single statement, hope helps some one.

Comment: Using the alter schema seems extremely slow. (I stopped it after 3 minutes for transfer a small table with 300 rows.) Instead, I used select * into exe.Employees from dbo.Employees

Comment: For empty tables run fast without any problem.

Answer (score 58):

```
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchema TRANSFER [OldSchema].[TableName]
```

I always have to use the brackets when I use the `ALTER SCHEMA` query in SQL, or I get an error message.

Comment: Adding square-brackets to the table name, table schema, and/or destination schema did not resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 35):

Try below

```
declare @sql varchar(8000), @table varchar(1000), @oldschema varchar(1000), @newschema   varchar(1000)

  set @oldschema = 'dbo'
  set @newschema = 'exe'

 while exists(select * from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = @oldschema)

  begin
      select @table = name from sys.tables 
      where object_id in(select min(object_id) from sys.tables where  schema_name(schema_id)  = @oldschema)

    set @sql = 'alter schema ' + @newschema + ' transfer ' + @oldschema + '.' + @table

   exec(@sql)
 end
```

Comment: I had to use `set @sql = 'alter schema [' + @newschema + '] transfer [' + @oldschema + '].' + @table` to make sure some special words/characters does not cause error.

Comment: This piece of sql will transfer all tables with the "dbo" schema to the "exe" schema. I used it to transfer a custom user schema to "dbo" for development.

Answer (score 17):

```
CREATE SCHEMA exe AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

ALTER SCHEMA exe
TRANSFER dbo.Employees
GO
```

Answer (score 7):

Through SSMS, I created a new schema by:

- Clicking the Security folder in the Object Explorer within my server,
- right clicked Schemas
- Selected "New Schema..."
- Named my new schema (exe in your case)
- Hit OK

I found this post to change the schema, but was also getting the same permissions error when trying to change to the new schema. I have several databases listed in my SSMS, so I just tried specifying the database and it worked:

```
USE (yourservername)  
ALTER SCHEMA exe TRANSFER dbo.Employees
```

Answer (score 5):

Your Code is:

```
FROM
 dbo.Employees
TO
 exe.Employees
```

I tried with this query.

```
ALTER SCHEMA exe TRANSFER dbo.Employees
```

Just write `create schema exe` and execute it

Answer (score 3):

Check out MSDN...

`CREATE SCHEMA`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx

Then

`ALTER SCHEMA`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx

Or you can check it on on SO...

[How do I move a table into a schema in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149159/how-do-i-move-a-table-into-a-schema-in-t-sql)

Comment: Can you show me example of how to create the schema in my situation ?

Answer (score 3):

For SQL2019:

```
ALTER SCHEMA [SCEMAYOUWANTTOTRANSFERTO] TRANSFER [CURRENTSCHEMA].[TABLENAME];
```

Example:

```
ALTER SCHEMA [dbo] TRANSFER [Curated].[MyTable];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're in the right database context in SSMS. Got the same error as you, but I knew the schema already existed. Didn't realize I was in 'MASTER' context. ALTER worked after I changed context to my database.

Answer (score 2):

In case, someone looking for lower version -

For SQL Server 2000:

sp_changeobjectowner @objname = 'dbo.Employess' , @newowner ='exe'

Answer (score 0):

Be very very careful renaming objects in sql.  You can cause dependencies to fail if you are not fully away with what you are doing.  Having said that this works easily(too much so) for renaming things provided you have access proper on the environment:

```
exec sp_rename 'Nameofobject', 'ReNameofobject'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in this scenario, sp_rename only works for changing the [name] value of an object. You can't change the schema with it. If you tried `exec sp_rename 'dbo.Employees', 'exe.Employees'` you would get the name [dbo].[exe.Employees]

Comment: ALTER SCHEMA (Name of Schema) TRANSFER (schemaName).(ObjectName);

Comment: Also note that when you change the schema of a table, any Views that use that table *won't* get updated.  You'll need to manually update the text (the schema names) in these views.  (Sigh...)

Answer (score 0):

also you can transfer your data from default schema 'dbo' to your schema
from wizard by
1-double click on db diagram
2- right click on your certian entity --> select properties
3- on right at identity , change the schema name