# How do I set the schema for Azure Mobile App tables?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Currently tables get created in the "dbo" schema, but I would like to set it to something different. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Currently tables get created in the "dbo" schema, but I would like to set it to something different. Is this possible?

For Node.js backend, you could add an app setting name `MS_TableSchema` with the value as your custom schema. You could log into Azure Portal and choose your app service, then click "All Settings > Application Settings", add the above setting under the App settings section. After created your new table via the **Add** button under "MOBILE > Easy tables" on Azure Portal, the new schema would be applied. For the existing table with the old schema, you may also need to alter your table with the newer schema. Moreover, you need to make sure your custom schema exists. Details you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482838/change-schema-name-of-table-in-sql). Also, you could follow the Defining a Table section under [TABLE CONTROLLER BASICS](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/15/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-8-table-controller-basics/), and the Alternative Schema section under [LINKING EXISTING TABLES](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/29/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-14-linking-existing-tables/).

For C# backend, you could follow adrian hall's book about [Changing the Mobile Schema](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/#changing-the-mobile-schema).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed note. I am using the C# backend and was able to make some progress using annotation: `[Table("TodoItems", Schema="mobile")]`. However, I noticed that even though my table was now created using the mobile schema, when I communicated to the server through my app, it would try to use 'dbo' again.

Comment: I just checked my table endpoints via the browser. Have you received any exceptions when communicating to your mobile app via your client app? Try to capture the exception in your client app and use fiddler to collect the network traces when handling the relevant operations.