# How do I change default schema of ms sql database using flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: sql-server, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My code snipit

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
inspector = inspect(db.engine)
```

Viewing default schema

```
print('Default schema: ', inspector.default_schema_name)
```

list of all available Schema

```
print('schema: ', inspector.get_schema_names())
```

Output:
Default schema:  dbo

schema:  ['admin', 'db_accessadmin', 'db_backupoperator', 'db_datareader', 'db_datawriter', 'db_ddladmin', 'db_denydatareader', 'db_denydatawriter', 'db_owner', 'db_securityadmin', 'dbo', 'devops', 'goal', 'etl', 'etl_logging', 'etl_on', 'evil', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'location', 'search', 'search_json', 'semantic', 'sys', 'tms', 'tms_on', 'tvclient', 'util', 'abc', 'xyz']

I want to use abc schema. How do I do?

Comment: use scalar query with this command "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()" this would give you the current schema name. Then, you can just use the returned name into your method.

Comment: It worked. Thanks @iSR5

But this gave me a current schema name. What I am looking for is to change the current schema.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482838/change-schema-name-of-table-in-sql