# How to use VBA to export a table from MS access to SQL Server, but with a specific schema?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, schema

Say I have the following code in VBA

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=EXAMPLESERVER;DATABASE=EXAMPLEDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=Yes].[test_import] FROM msaccess_table "
```

It works as expected, i.e. the contents of the *msaccess_table* that I have in my access file show up on sql server in the *test_import* table. Is there a way for me to change the above code so that the resulting *test_import* has a specific schema?

Comment: What happens if you change `.[test_import]`to `.[yourschema].[test_import]`

Comment: @siggemannen i get a runtime error 3067 (input for the query must contain at least one table/query). It seems like it doesn't recognize this as a valid query

Comment: Hmm, i wasn't able to find it, but you can always change the schema after inserting. Something like: `ALTER SCHEMA yournewschema TRANSFER OBJECT::test_import`. Schema name must of course exist already

Comment: What do you mean by "specific schema" - what do you want to change? - edit question to show example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Schema Name Of Table In SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482838/change-schema-name-of-table-in-sql)

Comment: @June7 I would like the end result to be like in that question. Is there no way to achieve that on exporting the table or do I have to ALTER SCHEMA after the export?

Comment: If it's just the name you want differenct, maybe https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_select_into.asp