# How to change schema of all tables, views and stored procedures in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-schema, database-migration, kentico

Recently we were having issues on our database server and after long efforts it was decided to change the database server. So we managed to restore the database on another server, change the connection string, etc. Everything was going as planned until we tried to access the website from a web browser.

We started getting errors about database objects not being found. Later we found out that it occured as a result of the modified schema name. Since there are hundreds of database objects (tables, views and stored procedures) in a Kentico database, it is not feasible to change all of them manually, one-by-one. Is there a practical way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you just haven't set your users default schema up incorrectly?

Comment: The question is nearly two years old but as far as I can remember it wasn't related to user's default schema.

Comment: Oh! for some reason it appeared at the top of the list!

Comment: Readers - Also see this Microsoft answer: https://support.managed.com/kb/a100/how-to-change-schema-of-mssql-tables-stored-procedures-and-views-all-at-the-same-time.aspx

Comment: I faced the same issue recently. what causes this the schema of objects to be changed while creating a new DB instance with existing user, and assigning privileges to the new instance?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible.**

To change the schema of a database object you need to run the following SQL script:

```
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.ObjectName
```

Where ObjectName can be the name of a table, a view or a stored procedure. The problem seems to be getting the list of all database objects with a given shcema name. Thankfully, there is a system table named sys.Objects that stores all database objects. The following query will generate all needed SQL scripts to complete this task:

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER [' + SysSchemas.Name + '].[' + DbObjects.Name + '];'
FROM sys.Objects DbObjects
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas SysSchemas ON DbObjects.schema_id = SysSchemas.schema_id
WHERE SysSchemas.Name = 'OldSchemaName'
AND (DbObjects.Type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'))
```

Where type 'U' denotes user tables, 'V' denotes views and 'P' denotes stored procedures.

Running the above script will generate the SQL commands needed to transfer objects from one schema to another. Something like this:

```
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.CONTENT_KBArticle;
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.Proc_Analytics_Statistics_Delete;
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.Proc_CMS_QueryProvider_Select;
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.COM_ShoppingCartSKU;
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.CMS_WebPart;
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.Polls_PollAnswer;
```

Now you can run all these generated queries to complete the transfer operation.

Comment: Nice solution. I used "WHERE SysSchemas.Name <> 'dbo'" instead to list all non-dbo bound objects.

Comment: And 'SO' denotes sequences

Comment: For **all  Tables** , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1149168/2218697) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10943302/2218697) to do it in single statement, hope helps some one.

Comment: want to transfer functions as well, you can add 'FN','TF' to in list. 'FN' for Scalar function, and 'TF' for Table function. for more, ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx

Comment: This is just perfect answer. Thanks @anar for save my time.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the SQL I ran, to move all tables in my database (spread across several schemas) into the "dbo" schema:

```
DECLARE 
    @currentSchemaName nvarchar(200),
    @tableName nvarchar(200)

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY 1, 2

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(400)

OPEN tableCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @currentSchemaName, @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER ' + @currentSchemaName + '.' + @tableName
    PRINT @SQL

    EXEC (@SQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @currentSchemaName, @tableName
END

CLOSE tableCursor 
DEALLOCATE tableCursor
```

Phew!

Answer (score 7):

You may use following script by just copy/paste for all objects

***NOTE***: You need to Change schema names in script !

```
DECLARE @OldSchema VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @NewSchema VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @OldSchema = 'dbo'
SET @NewSchema = 'Inf'

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA  ['+ @NewSchema +'] TRANSFER [' + SysSchemas.Name + '].[' + DbObjects.Name + '];' AS Cmd
    FROM sys.Objects DbObjects
    INNER JOIN sys.Schemas SysSchemas ON DbObjects.schema_id = SysSchemas.schema_id
    WHERE SysSchemas.Name = @OldSchema
    AND (DbObjects.Type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'))
OPEN tableCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO  @SQL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO  @SQL
END
CLOSE tableCursor 
DEALLOCATE tableCursor 
PRINT '*** Finished ***'
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the tip.. Here is my update to same, where I added a crlf to output as well as put brackets around the SchemaName and ObjectName, because some of the objects had a '-' in the name and the brackets solved that naming error.

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER [' + SysSchemas.Name + '].[' +      DbObjects.Name + '];'
+ CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)+ 'GO '+ CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)
FROM sys.Objects DbObjects
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas SysSchemas ON DbObjects.schema_id =     SysSchemas.schema_id
WHERE SysSchemas.Name = 'OldSchemaName'
AND (DbObjects.Type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on combining anar's and Hank's answers.
***I also changed the names of the system views and columns as I am using SQL Server 2019 and it seems that Microsoft has changed the first-letter case for all of these objects.***

```sql
SELECT
    'ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER [' + ss.name + '].[' + so.name + '];' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM
    sys.objects so
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON
    so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
WHERE
    ss.name = 'OldSchemaName'
    AND (so.type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'))
```