# Loop and Rename all tables in my database

Tags: sql-server

Due to certain requirement, I need to add some prefix to my tables.The new naming convention must apply to all existing tables in my database. example:  I have [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942901/renaming-multiple-tables)  but did not meet my need.

```
TableA,TableB,TableC etc.    
My new tables should look:    
TableA_CA,TableB_CA,TableC_CA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to do this without looping. Try this.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += 'exec sp_rename ' + NAME + ',' + NAME + '_CA '
FROM   sys.tables
WHERE  NAME IN ( 'TableA', 'TableB', 'TableC' )

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql
```