# add schema to a missed table in SQL after checking if the table exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I am trying to add schema to the table 'myTable' which was missed. I want the table to be under 'dbo.myTable'

**EDIT**

I am not able to add code but the stack overflow is not allowing.. I want to check if exists from sys.tables and do the alter schema transfer.

[image]

Comment: Not clear at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equivalent in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520999/create-table-if-not-exists-equivalent-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move a table into a schema in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149159/how-do-i-move-a-table-into-a-schema-in-t-sql)

Comment: I am not able to add code but the stack overflow is not allowing.. I want to check if exists from sys.tables and do the alter schema transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default schema is `dbo`, but if it is in a different schema for some reason you can [**`alter schema`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423(v=sql.110).aspx) to `transfer` the table.

```
alter schema dbo transfer [current_schema_name].mytable;
```

To transfer a schema if a table exists you could use something like this:

```
if exists (select 1
           from sys.objects o
           where schema_name(o.schema_id)<>N'dbo'
             and o.name = 'mytable'
           )
alter schema dbo transfer test.mytable;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TEBRQL57704

Comment: is there a way to check if the table exists from sys.tables and perform the alter schema like your answer?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

A table in SQL Server will always belong to a schema, with default settings it will belong to the dbo schema if no other is specified.