# Sql server schema difference between custom and "dbo"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, naming, sql-view

I've a shared web hosting and Sql Server with it.

When I create a `View` or `Stored Procedure` via Sql Server Management Studio it appends as prefix my username instead of `dbo`.

Suppose my username is `UserJustWork` which I use while connecting to remote sql server.

`SP`s and `View`s are being named as:

```
UserJustWork.Users_Get -- SP
UserJustWork.ActiveUsers -- View
```

According to hundreds of people (e.g. SQLMenace's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769639/2371858)) using prefix makes sql faster on finding object.

Sure, it is shared sql server (that means there are so many people using it).

What I wonder is that does it make better performance using `UserJustWork` instead of `dbo`?

Comment: what you call `prefix` is actually `Schema`, the best reason to have schema for `users` in a shared `sql server` is to bring isolation among different users. you can read a bit more [here](http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2008/tutorial/sql_server_database_schemas.cfm)

Comment: It doesn't make any difference but as you said its shared hosting so its good to give custom name.

Comment: Why is it good to give custom name than dbo? I am already requesting with my username and password, so sql knows which account's function will be executed even there are other same named functions. So, why use custom name?